# how to list all switched folders in a SVN working copy

Tags: visual-studio-code, svn, branch, tortoisesvn

i am using the Tortoise SVN client to work with a SVN repo. To develop a new feature I branch the specific module. If the feature is more complex i have to branch multiple modules in different parts of the software. This gets at some point quiet confusing which modules are switched and which are not.

So is there a way to ask svn which folders in the working copy are switched?
I use vscode with johnstoncode.svn-scm extension.

Comment: Could you please give an example of the problem? It seems like you are not branching the whole SVN folder, but just some parts of it. Imagine I have to checkout one version of your project. If you have to send me more than just one URL then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I always make different working copy checkouts for different branches with includes branch in name to easily see which brank you work with